# join two csv using key columns

Tags: bash, csv

I would like to join two files using the key column the name of the city. I want to join only the data of the cities that are repeated in both csv...

For example

File1.csv

```
London, 10,15
Rome, 12,18
Paris, 8, 16
Lissabon, 10,17
```

File2.csv

```
London, 11,16
Berlin, 13,19
Paris, 12,18
Lissabon, 11,19
```

Result I wish,

```
London,10,15,11,16 
Paris,8,16,12,18
Lissabon,10,17,11,19
```

How can I do it in bash?

Comment: What to do with the part that doesn't match ?

Answer (score 2):

bash has a `join` command, though it requires that the input be sorted:

```
$ join -j 1 -t ',' <(sort File1.csv) <(sort File2.csv)
Lissabon, 10,17, 11,19
London, 10,15, 11,16
Paris, 8, 16, 12,18
```

Comment: Hmm this changes the order of input data.

Comment: Technically, `join` has nothing to do with `bash`, though. It's just a command that exists on many/most Linux/Unix systems (in a couple different flavors). You can just as well run it if your shell is `sh`, `ksh`, `zsh`, or even `csh`...

Comment: @EnricAgudPique If you choose this answer or the other check to accept it, if you find useful vote it up!

Answer (score 1):

Using this `awk`:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$0;next} $1 in a{p=$1; sub(/^[^,]+, */, "");
         print a[p], $0}' OFS=, file1 file2
London, 10,15,11,16
Paris, 8, 16,12,18
Lissabon, 10,17,11,19
```